# How many copies of static variable/function is made in different threads?

Tags: c, static

Does the stack of a thread/process make seperate copy of static function/method or is it shared.if it is shared where it is kept/stored and how does the mechanism works in C.

Rgds,
Softy

Comment: C does not define anything to do with threads or processes.  This is all dependent on the operating system.

Comment: @xyz somebody has a high reputation on SO does that give him the right to downvote and  contradict evry question a noob posts. - "with great power comes the great responsibilty " , i respect the Spidey and wish he could make my post more lively besides belittling it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static function is used to limit the scope of the function within file. As it is a function(code) it goes to text(code) segment.

You can understand in details from following article

http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory